# Writing html in javascript and angularjs translate is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am writing html with angularJS translate tag in javascript than tranlate is not working. If I am using it in regular html translate is working fine.

like I am writing html in jquery

`$("#msg1").html('');
var htmls = "<h2>{{'loginWelComeBack' | translate }}</h2>";
$("#msg1").html(htmls);`

In page I am using like this.

```
<div id="msg1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression {{'loginWelComeBack' | translate}} is not executed in angular context. 
You need compile service which let angular know that it is an angular expression.

Try this code:

```
// Inject $compile, $scope in your code 
$("#msg1").html($compile(htmls)($scope));
```

[Refer here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx) for more information about compile

Comment: Hi, Vu... Thanks a lot for quick reply. Can we make this solution generic. I mean if I am having 3 div and I want to add content of all 3 div dynamically. like the one you solved. I mean can we create on function and pass 3 html values. I never looked into Angular js. This is the first time I am looking into and very frustrated as I need to see everything on google. Please help me. I will be highly thankful of you.

Comment: I added a directive named 'compileHtml' allowing you to compile any content in your div. It is just a small example for you to play at start time. When you can control angular, you will soon see that it give you a powerful tool to work with html. https://plnkr.co/edit/USiWQLx0cO3riscgrAW2?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should not use jQuery for setting texts at all when dealing with AngularJS. 
Have a look ad ng-bind, ng-if and $scope, so the AngularJS basics.

You should create a directive for that, or at least a simple angular markup like this.

```
<h2 ng-if="loginWelcomeBack" ng-translate="loginWelcomeBack"></h2>
```

If $scope.loginWelcomeBack in the controller is set to false, it will not be shown, if its a value, it will be defined.

Also a quite good practice (on smaller same as bitter sites) is to keep your translation strings grouped. 
Eg:

```
"COMMON_OK": "ok",
"COMMON_CANCEL": "cancel",
"ACCOUNT_WELCOME": "Welcome back {{user}}"
```

For the latter one you could insert that "user" like:

```
<h2 ng-if="loginWelcomeBack" translate="loginWelcomeBack" translate-value-name="user.name"></h2>
// $scope.user = { name: "John Doe", id: 1, whatever: "foobar" } must be defined in the controller of course.
```

Working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/V3Tnoj7jJGD8wY6SUUKc?p=preview

You can check out details here: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement

And since it seems you need more basic knowledge, the official docs provide a nice tutorial https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01